# How do wireless router control panel pages work?

Tags: networking, browser, webpage, router, wireless-networking

I understand that for regular web pages on the WWW, a browser will send a request to the server hosting that page, and then renders the page sent back. (I know there's more to it than that)

However, how does that request process work for the page that displays on my browser when I access my wireless router's control panel page?

I'm assuming the page is stored somewhere in my router's memory, with my personal preferences and settings stored in a file or local DB. I assume this because the page can only be access from one in wireless network, if there isn't remote access allowed.

If that's the case, then how does it work between the browser and the router? When I type in the reserved address for my router i.e. 192.168.1.1, what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: When you are accessing your router's control panel, the router is acting as the server. Your browser doesn't know any difference. When you enter the router's IP, the router will process the request instead of going to the web to send the request to a different server (indicated by the IP or URL) for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Router has a web server on it, albeit a small one.
- It also has webpages installed onto its flash/nvram chip that allow you to modify its values. When you modify a value and save it, depending on router setup, it can store it in ram which is run off a battery so it is remembered even when the router is unplugged or it can contain a flash disk / other types of persistant memory.
- When you save from the web interface, there are a few ways it can communicate with the router operating system. For instance, it might use `cgi` to call programs written in c, python, php, or other languages that are also stored on the router.

If this interests you, I recommend learning about OpenWRT, it's where I get my information from. In fact, I helped build python tornado and install it on our Router OS. If you want to see a pretty awesome router web page setup, look into LUCI, it's the default web setup software: http://luci.subsignal.org/

Comment: I have heard of OpenWRT. It's a router firmware like DD-WRT right?

Comment: Yes. DD-WRT is less open-sourced and less supported (from what I heard on forums and things, citation needed of course) and supports less devices, but essentially does the same job as OpenWRT.